# Can't update the values when having a dynamic relationship. Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-nova

I already have done a long investigation about this issue on the Google and GitHub issues on the Laravel Nova.

I do have next code, which is described below:

```php
   /**
    * @var array
    */
    private $parentClasses = [
        'activity' => Activity::class,
        'movie' => PlayTogether::class,
        'book' => Book::class
    ];

    /**
     * Returns a parent class/entity to which Skills are described
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo|Activity|PlayTogether|Book
     */
    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo($this->parentClasses[$this->attributes['type']], 'entity_id', 'id');
    }
```

When accessing the edit mode, on the `Update` I am getting an exception:
[image: Error on the Update]

While logging `$this->attributes['type']`, I am getting an empty string.

How could I solve this issue? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue with one of my models. The model have dynamic relational field, and issue occured when trying to update this model. When updating the model - all it's fields and relations are empty. I 'solved' this issue by checking field on emptiness in places where it's needed.

```
if (!empty($this->relatedModel)) {
    // do someting
}
```

Seems to be a bug inside Nova.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. It would be better to not simply describe the solution but to provide the code to solve OP problem